# Xml parsing in powershell:Adding and removing

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I am trying to add and remove entries from xml file using powershell. This is how my xml file content looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source>
  <name>namevalue</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>connval</url>
    <driver-name>DriverVal</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>username</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <password-encrypted>encryptedpwd</password-encrypted>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

I need to remove encryptedpwd entry and add
unencryptedpwd

I have been trying with following piece of code.

```
$file = "Path of xml file with content as mentioned above"
Get-ChildItem $file | % {
    [Xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName

    $addItem = $xml.CreateElement('password')
    $addItem.PsBase.InnerText = 'unencryptedpwd'
    $xml.'jdbc-data-source'.'jdbc-driver-params'.AppendChild($addItem) | Out-Null

    $nodes = $xml.'jdbc-data-source'.'jdbc-driver-params'
    $nodes | % {
        $child_node = $_.SelectSingleNode('password-encrypted')
        $_.RemoveChild($child_node) | Out-Null
    }
    $xml.OuterXml | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

It has got following problems.

1. It does not remove the child 'password-encrypted'.
2. It removes all newline breaks.

Can anyone help on this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another but similar approach is like below:

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source>
  <name>namevalue</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>connval</url>
    <driver-name>DriverVal</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>username</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <password-encrypted>encryptedpwd</password-encrypted>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
'@

# remove the 'password-encrypted' node
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//password-encrypted')
[void]$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)

# create and add the new 'unencryptedpwd' node
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement('unencryptedpwd')
$newNode.InnerText = 'your unencrypted password'
[void]$xml.'jdbc-data-source'.'jdbc-driver-params'.AppendChild($newNode)

$xml.Save('D:\Test\test.xml')
```

P.S. There is a better way to load the xml than using `Get-Content` that automatically takes the documents encoding into account:

```
# load the xml file. This way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xml.Load($_.FullName)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out $xml.Load method, I used that and at least I am sure now that XML is in right format. However, $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//password-encrypted') does not give any output.

Comment: @Vikas Then, are you sure you gave us a correct example, because it works for me...

Comment: So, I was able to narrow down the problem, In file there are attributes available for  top node <jdbc-data-source xsi:schemaLocation="http://Link0 http://Link00" xmlns="http://Link1" xmlns:sec="http://Link2" xmlns:wls="http://Link3" xmlns:xsi="http://Link4> . If i remove xsi and all xmlns paramters,code works. Any idea how to handle this within code?

Comment: @Vikas So it seems you have an XML with namespaces. Those are more difficult to handle.. Why did you leave these out in the example xml? I suggest you post a new question, this time with an example that does contain the namespace declarations and also leave the links as they are

Answer (score 0):

First, your sample xml isn't well formed - the root element needs to be properly closed: the bottom `<jdbc-data-source>` should be `</jdbc-data-source>`.

Assuming that's fixed, you need to parse the xml using the xml parser, and use xpath to locate, delete and insert your elements.

So, if I understand you correclty, this should work:

```
$xml=[Xml]@"
[your xml above, fixed]

"@
$newpass=@'

     <password>unencryptedpwd</password>

'@
#locate the element to delete
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//password-encrypted') 
#go to its parent and delete the child
$dest = $node.ParentNode
$dest.RemoveChild($node)
#import the new element as a fragment
$xmlFragment=$xml.CreateDocumentFragment()
$xmlFragment.InnerXML=$newpass
#finally, insert it in the xml
$dest.AppendChild($xmlFragment)
```

The modified xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source>
  <name>namevalue</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>connval</url>
    <driver-name>DriverVal</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>username</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
     <password>unencryptedpwd</password>
</jdbc-driver-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. XML was a typo which you already found out. Coming back to solution you provided, I am getting following error. ```` You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:10 char:1 + $dest.RemoveChild($node) ```` Apparently, $node is not getting any value from path statement, I tried by removing one ‘/‘, still same problem. Same problem while adding as well, since both are using same variable $dest which is getting null value of $node.

Comment: @Vikas Not sure what the problem is - unless your actual xml is somehow different from the one in the question. I ran this (based on the fixed xml in the question) is both Powershell ISE and VSC without issues.

Comment: I used the exact code in PS ISE, and it throws the same error.              [xml]$xml=@'
[above xml]
'@

$newpass=@'

     <password>unencryptedpwd</password>

'@
#locate the element to delete
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//password-encrypted') 
#go to its parent and delete the child
$dest = $node.ParentNode
$dest.RemoveChild($node)
#import the new element as a fragment
$xmlFragment=$xml.CreateDocumentFragment()
$xmlFragment.InnerXML=$newpass
#finally, insert it in the xml
$dest.AppendChild($xmlFragment)

Comment: @Vikas    Take [a look here.](https://tio.run/##bVLJasMwEL3rK4QJODnYbm892E5KQqDQjW4ESg@qNSQusiRkKW6@PtV4yUJzMZq3zBuNrFUDpt6AEPv96LcS2eeqEl@zgKRTX9GtJ0sls@A6vgooyELxUq6z4P1tGd0E05ykP/y7iDizLKqVMwXkhNJUsgpy/GyZcJAmbY1Epzal7xtpZlhVI@wJZ0ReKCm9IU2w6OBe2voX7fkDBadwJ9RGaTC2hL7hEdoNwDCXq8EcR@qZdtCWQiJNunpolZz3OtSHuFSzum6U4ZHfkdlpCzw/nHTDveO/ABeSXNrIgJ5ulQQzMpLQYJ9sFhJCz3JzJy/neWeITsWBZhSfOH4FAYV99Q8p4NHj4zC5MF44oWTEobZoQ3v8zAxIi46OiF@gUluYb0rBx61kQjBgadi68sqsTZsbYBYWqnCIDdz4XBrfSQlm9XCfDXfsI261Bsn7iBPDhBACxUZ1N3py1rsr/w//AQ)

Comment: So, I was able to narrow down the problem, In file there are attributes available for  top node <jdbc-data-source xsi:schemaLocation="http://Link0 http://Link00" xmlns="http://Link1" xmlns:sec="http://Link2" xmlns:wls="http://Link3" xmlns:xsi="http://Link4> . If i remove xsi and all xmlns paramters,code works. Any idea how to handle this within code?

Comment: @Vikas Sigh, that's why I asked you to make sure your actual and sample xml are the same... Your actual file has namespaces, which have to be dealt with separately. I suggest you post a new question (so as not to clutter this one any more) with a representative sample of the actual xml.